# IF function SharePoint - Not Empty Column

Tags: sharepoint

How would I specify if a column is not empty or blank in an IF statement - in a calculated column formula?

Answer (score 25):

There is a function ISBLANK([Column Name]) that you can also use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([My Column]),"EMPTY",[My Column])
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use the LEN([column]) function i.e.. IF(LEN([column]) > 0,'yay','nay')

Answer (score 0):

To check if column is null/blank best way is to do something like this:

`=IF([column1]<>"","Not blank", "")`

the reason this is best because you can add and & or into the formula